# Java restful Dynamic web to access dropbox

Tags: java, web-services, rest, dropbox

I'm good at **javaSE** but very new to **javaEE** concepts. I want to create a web service that will do tasks on dropbox like **uploading files, getting files** etc.
By following the basic documentation of dropbox [core api](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/start/java), i'm so far being able to develop a simple desktop console app to access and upload dropbox contents.

here is what i did:

```
package com.teamincredibles.dropboxapp;
import com.dropbox.core.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, DbxException {
    // Get your app key and secret from the Dropbox developers website.
    final String APP_KEY = "xxxxxxxxxxx";
    final String APP_SECRET = "xxxxxxxxxxx";

    DbxAppInfo appInfo = new DbxAppInfo(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET);

    DbxRequestConfig config = new DbxRequestConfig("JavaTutorial/1.0",
      Locale.getDefault().toString());
    DbxWebAuthNoRedirect webAuth = new DbxWebAuthNoRedirect(config, appInfo);

    // Have the user sign in and authorize your app.
    String authorizeUrl = webAuth.start();
    System.out.println("1. Go to: " + authorizeUrl);
    System.out.println("2. Click \"Allow\" (you might have to log in first)");
    System.out.println("3. Copy the authorization code.");
    String code = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)).readLine().trim();

    // This will fail if the user enters an invalid authorization code.
    DbxAuthFinish authFinish = webAuth.finish(code);
    String accessToken = authFinish.accessToken;

    DbxClient client = new DbxClient(config, accessToken);

    System.out.println("Linked account: " + client.getAccountInfo().displayName);

    File inputFile = new File("work.txt");
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
    try {
      DbxEntry.File uploadedFile = client.uploadFile("/work.txt",
        DbxWriteMode.add(), inputFile.length(), inputStream);
      System.out.println("Uploaded: " + uploadedFile.toString());
    } finally {
      inputStream.close();
    }

    DbxEntry.WithChildren listing = client.getMetadataWithChildren("/");
    System.out.println("Files in the root path:");
    for (DbxEntry child: listing.children) {
      System.out.println("  " + child.name + ": " + child.toString());
    }

    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("work.txt");
    try {
      DbxEntry.File downloadedFile = client.getFile("/work.txt", null,
        outputStream);
      System.out.println("Metadata: " + downloadedFile.toString());
    } finally {
      outputStream.close();
    }
  }
}
```

Now i'm confused how to make such web service where i can just add actions in url like: http://localhost:8080//myservice/dropbox/access/all

Hope you understand my point.

I want a restfull web service for this which **i can call in other web services**. I've searched tons of web but can't find a simpler way that i can understand.

Any help would be Appriciated.